# Add data in a row (from another file) if that row consists of a particular string(city)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have two csv files and I want to add number of confirmed cases in front of the state in another csv file. Also this had to match with the date as well.

```
 #updated.csv
    address         Date time
    Albany,us       1/30/2020
    Atlanta, US     1/30/2020
```

2nd file

```
#covid.csv
       Combined_Key                 Confirmed     date updated
    Campbell, Wyoming, US            4             1/22/2020
    Cape Girardeau, Missouri, US     5             1/22/2020
```

the result I want

```
address         Date time    Confirmed
 Albany,us       1/30/2020         5
 Atlanta, US     1/30/2020         6
```

the code I am trying is not working

```
data = pd.read_csv("updated.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("covid19_combined_csv.csv",dtype={'Active':int,'Admin2':str,'Combined_Key':str,'Confirmed': int, 'Country/Region': str,'Country_Region':str,'FIPS':int,'Deaths':int,'Last Update':str,'Last_Update':str,'Lat': int,'Latitude':int,'Long_':int,'Longitude':int,'Province/State':str,'Province_State':str, 'Recovered':int})


a = df['Country/Region']
b = df['Confirmed']
#c = data['C']
for i in a:
 for j in b:
     data['confirmed'] = pd.np.where(data.Address.str.contains(i) , j, "n/a")
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should show some more information in your question. It is hard to guess what you want to achieve. I assume you should extract the State from the `covid.csv` in a new column and use group by that new column to calculate the number of Confirmed deaths per state. Join the `updated.csv` dataframe on State and sum the number of the new confirmed deaths and the old value that you had stored.

Code is not tested, but might help to direct you in the right direction:

```py
data = pd.read_csv("updated.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("covid19_combined_csv.csv",
                 dtype={'Active':int,'Admin2':str,'Combined_Key':str,'Confirmed': int, 'Country/Region': str,'Country_Region':str,'FIPS':int,'Deaths':int,'Last Update':str,'Last_Update':str,'Lat': int,'Latitude':int,'Long_':int,'Longitude':int,'Province/State':str,'Province_State':str, 'Recovered':int})

# Get state assuming last two values are State, US
df['state'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.split(',')[-2:]))
# Assume this column. Cannot test.
df['deaths_by_state'] = df.groupby(state)['Confirmed'].sum()
# Combine two tables
total_data = data.merge(df, on='state')
# Not sure if you want to sum the values from the updated and covid CSV
total_data['TotalConfirmed'] = df['deaths_by_state'] + df['Confirmed']
```